# How to unfilter table rows when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a jquery script that filters rows with a looping function when a check box is checked, or words are typed in a text box. The textbox works perfectly when you erase the words it will unfilter, however the check boxes when you uncheck them it doesn't unfilter. It will switch between the two check boxes for on and off.

However, you can trick it to unfilter the checkboxes applied filter by filtering by name and typing in the textbox and then erasing what you typed.

Thus,
I don't know why when you uncheck a check box it doesn't unfilter it because how could it keep applying the filter every-time it loops if the box is not checked.

```
var $rows = $("#data tr"),
    $filter = $("#filter");

$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filterText = $filter.val().toLowerCase();
    $rows.each(function () {
        var $row = $(this);
        $row.toggle($row.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) > -1);
    });
});


var $row_on = $("#data tr"),
    $filter_poweron = $("#poweron");

if(($filter_poweron).is(':checked')) {
    var filterText_poweron = $filter_poweron.val().toLowerCase();
    $row_on.each(function () {
        var $row_d = $(this);
        $row_d.toggle($row_d.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText_poweron) > -1);
    });
}


var $row_off = $("#data tr"),
    $filter_poweroff = $("#poweroff");

if(($filter_poweroff).is(':checked')) {
    var filterText_poweroff = $filter_poweroff.val().toLowerCase();
    $row_off.each(function () {
        var $row_do = $(this);
        $row_do.toggle($row_do.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText_poweroff) > -1);
    });
}


<td width='200' align='left'>
              <br><br>Filter: <input type='text' name='' id='filter' value='' style='width:270px;' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Filter VM List." placeholder='Type to filter'>
              <br><input type="checkbox" id="poweron" value="1O">PoweredOn <input type="checkbox" id='poweroff' value="0F"> PoweredOff
</td>
```

Comment: I don't see any event handler for the checkboxes in your code...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to move the `if(($filter_poweron).is(':checked')) {...}` stuff inside an event listener so that it runs every time the checkbox is clicked or changed.

Something like:

```
var $rows = $("#data tr");

$("#filter").keyup(function() {
  var filterText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $rows.each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    $row.toggle($row.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) > -1);
  });
});

$("#poweron, #poweroff").on('click change', function() {
  var filterText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
  $rows.each(function() {
    var $row_do = $(this);
    var showRow = isChecked ? $row_do.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) > -1 : true;
    $row_do.toggle(showRow);
  });
});
```

A couple side notes:
`var $rows = $("#data tr")` and `var $row_on = $("#data tr")` and `var $row_off = $("#data tr")` are all redundant (querying the dom 3 times with the same query). You just need one variable for `$rows`. Also, you don't need parens around `($filter_poweron).is()`.